# have diff_data show the full comparison of names from two lists

Tags: r

I'm a little new to R. I'm trying to compare two columns from two different datasets. The information in the columns is a list of the Scientific Names of several plant species. I'm trying to Compare the list from one data set to the other to see what name is missing from one or the other.

I have been having trouble finding a code that can isolate those two columns. I have tried `diff_data` from the `daff` package and got a good comparison list but the list stopped and did not continue the comparison. How do I make diff_data display the full list?

> diff_data(List1,List2)
> Daff Comparison: ‘List1’ vs. ‘List2’
> First 6 and last 6 patch lines:
> A:A            B:B
> @@  Family         ScientificName
> 1:1         Family1      Name1
> 2:2     ->  Family1      Name2
> 3:-     --- Family2      Name3
> 4:-     --- Family2      Name4
> 5:3     ->  Family2      Name5
> ...     ... ...            ...
> 994:-   --- Family      Viola purpurea subsp. purpurea
> 995:-   --- VIOLACEAE      Viola quercetorum
> 996:-   --- VIOLACEAE      Viola sheltonii
> 997:743 ->  VITACEAE       Vitis girdiana
> 998:-   --- WOODSIACEAE    Cystopteris fragilis
> 999:-   --- ZYGOPHYLLACEAE Tribulus terrestris

Comment: If you save the results of the `diff_data` function (e.g. `result <- diff_data(List1,List2)`) does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're asking for, but perhaps this example using [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) functions will help:

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Load example dataset from the 'tidyverse' package
data(fruit)

# Set seed to allow reproducible sampling
set.seed(123)

# Create two dataframes by sampling the 'fruit' dataset
df1 <- data.frame(fruit = sample(fruit, 20, replace = FALSE),
                  values = 1:20)
df2 <- data.frame(fruit = sample(fruit, 40, replace = FALSE),
                  values = rnorm(40))

# Find fruit common to both
dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by = "fruit")
#>           fruit values.x     values.y
#> 1           fig        1 -0.006198262
#> 2    ugli fruit        2 -0.778997240
#> 3       kumquat        8  1.242918775
#> 4     tamarillo        9 -0.900791751
#> 5          date       10  1.685887244
#> 6      rambutan       11 -0.520869344
#> 7  blood orange       13 -1.318937604
#> 8   dragonfruit       14  0.619283535
#> 9    blackberry       15 -0.886436716
#> 10   star fruit       16 -1.048975504

# Find fruit in df1 but not in df2
dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = "fruit")
#>           fruit values
#> 1     nectarine      3
#> 2    cantaloupe      4
#> 3        quince      5
#> 4    kiwi fruit      6
#> 5      mulberry      7
#> 6  passionfruit     12
#> 7        raisin     17
#> 8     pineapple     18
#> 9    cloudberry     19
#> 10        guava     20

# Find fruit in df2 but not in df1
dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1, by = "fruit")
#>                fruit      values
#> 1          tangerine -0.16393097
#> 2         strawberry -0.93438506
#> 3          cherimoya  0.39370865
#> 4         goji berry  0.40363146
#> 5             jujube  0.02884391
#> 6            currant -0.43212979
#> 7             durian  1.68987252
#> 8          persimmon  1.22839278
#> 9              olive  0.27602348
#> 10        redcurrant  1.62320252
#> 11       huckleberry -1.07006823
#> 12             grape -0.24168977
#> 13        elderberry -0.46820048
#> 14       bell pepper -0.77297823
#> 15      blackcurrant  2.14991934
#> 16        breadfruit -1.33435363
#> 17      canary melon  0.49587048
#> 18        clementine  1.23397624
#> 19        gooseberry  0.63436212
#> 20 purple mangosteen  0.41202227
#> 21       pomegranate  0.79358531
#> 22            pomelo -0.15241063
#> 23         cranberry -0.22889582
#> 24       salal berry -0.73502616
#> 25            lychee -1.42768578
#> 26            cherry -0.68570685
#> 27            feijoa -0.27933353
#> 28          bilberry -0.78273028
#> 29         raspberry -0.37480009
#> 30          cucumber -0.31939381
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks for this idea I will try it. I eventually got the function to work by using intersect and adding $ to specify a column but for some reason there were a couple matches it did not pick up so I will try this one next